# NullPointerException while setting image in a Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to set an image from a drawable inside an ImageView in a Fragment. The above code throws a `NullPointerException` at the line,

> imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.featured_one);

```
public class FeaturedTwo extends Fragment {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_one, container, false);

        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.featured_two_image);

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.featured_one);

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Please help me find a solution.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.anandzoom.appytizertest.FeaturedTwo.onCreateView(FeaturedTwo.java:28)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
```

XML of featured_one,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/featured_one_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: see my edit use setImageDrawable() like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fragment use view's context instead of `getActivity()`

**EDIT:** And also correct your imageview id use featured_one_image instead of featured_one_image.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_one, container, false);
    imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.featured_one_image);

    // set drawable image like it
    imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.featured_one));


    return rootView;

}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception at imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.featured_one);

Comment: @Anand Kumar check edit at setImageDrawable() methods

Comment: still throws NullPointerException....java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Anand Kumar you have get wrong id correct it currently you are using featured_two_image instead of featured_one_image

Comment: Thanks a lot... got it now :)

Comment: wlcm  friend enjoy android!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136230/discussion-between-anand-kumar-and-gargs).

Answer (score 2):

Use `rootView.findViewById` instead of getActivity because your layout is inside fragment not inside activity.

You have also wrong id , into your xml is named "featured_one_image" but you get "featured_two_image".

So change your code 
`imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.featured_two_image);` with `imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.featured_one_image);`

Answer (score 2):

Hey you need to find your view within fragment not in parent activity.

just replace

```
imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.featured_one_image);
```

with

```
imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.featured_two_image);
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception at imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.featured_one);

Comment: can you paste xml fie for featured_one

Comment: Thanks a lot... I've got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the ImageView from your rootView.

Call

`imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.featured_one_image);`

Edit: The ImageView inside your rootView is **featured_one_image**, not **featured_two_image**

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception at imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.featured_one);

Comment: @AnandKumar Call `imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.featured_one_image);`

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.featured_two_image);
```

use this:

```
imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.featured_two_image);
```